# ApacheでのSSL設定に関して

Tags: apache, ssl

お世話になります。
Ubuntu 18.04、Apache 2.4.29、OpenSSL 1.1.1bの環境でSSLの設定を行おうとしています。
なお証明書はcertbotでワイルドカード証明書を取得しています。
普通にSSLの設定はできたのですが、わけあって、古い端末（WindowsXP+IE8等）に対応する必要があり、下記サイトを参考に設定ファイルのサンプルを作成しました。

https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/

で、当方はUbuntuを利用しているため、「/etc/apache2/mods-available/ssl.conf」を下記のように指定しました。

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>    
    SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
    SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom 512
    SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
    SSLRandomSeed connect file:/dev/urandom 512

    AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crt
    AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl .crl

    SSLPassPhraseDialog  exec:/usr/share/apache2/ask-for-passphrase

    SSLSessionCache     shmcb:${APACHE_RUN_DIR}/ssl_scache(512000)
    SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

    SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:SEED:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!RSAPSK:!aDH:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA:!SRP
        SSLHonorCipherOrder on
    SSLProtocol all
    SSLCompression          off
    SSLSessionTickets       off
    SSLUseStapling          on
    SSLStaplingResponderTimeout 5
    SSLStaplingReturnResponderErrors off
    SSLStaplingCache        shmcb:/var/run/ocsp(128000)
</IfModule>
```

また、バーチャルホストには、下記のように記述しています。

```
（非SSLサイトのバーチャルホストの設定は省略）
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName test.example.com:443
        AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
        DocumentRoot /home/[ユーザー名]/public_html/test.example.com
        ErrorLog /home/[ユーザー名]/log/test.example.com/error.log
        CustomLog /home/[ユーザー名]/log/test.example.com/access.log combined

        <IfModule mod_userdir.c>
        UserDir public_html
        UserDir disabled root
        <Directory /home/*/public_html>
        AllowOverride All
        Options All
        Options -Indexes
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        </Directory>
        </IfModule>

        <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
        </IfModule>

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile  /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

この状態で

```
a2ensite test.example.conf
a2enmod ssl
```

を実行して、サーバーを再起動しました。
その後、

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html

で該当のドメインを入力して、SSLのテストをしましたが、下記のメッセージが出ているため、WindowsXP+IE8等では接続できないものと思われます。

```
IE 8 / XP   No FS 1   No SNI 2
Server sent fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

なにかほかに設定が必要でしょうか。
アドバイスをいただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE 8 では SNI がサポートされていないとのことですので、SSLバーチャルホストが 1つ、もしくは、最初の SSLバーチャルホストを test.example.com とする必要があります。
そうなっていますでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。
あまり詳しくないのですが、最初の SSLバーチャルホストを変更するというのは、バーチャルホストの設定の「ServerName」の部分を「test.example.com」に変更すればよいということでしょうか。
もしそうだとすると、現在の最初のSSLバーチャルホストでは、「ServerName any」となっているので、これでは問題があるということでしょうか。

Comment: 『最初のSSLバーチャルホストでは、「ServerName any」となっているので』→このバーチャルホストを使っていないのであれば、無効にしてみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。無効にしてみましたが、変わらないようです。そもそも特定のサブドメインだけ現在設定しようとしているサーバーに向けているのがだめなんでしょうか。独自ドメインのアドレス（example.com）は、別のサーバーで利用したいので、こういう設定になってるんですが。

Comment: サブドメインだけであることは関係ないと思います。
実際に IE 8 で接続できないのでしょうか？

Comment: やはりそうですよね。IE8でのテストをしたいのですが、手元に実機がないため、質問文に書いてあるURLでテストしている状況です。ただ、WinXP+IE6では接続できないので、たぶんできないと思います。

Comment: openssl で DES が無効になっているのではないでしょうか。
https://superuser.com/questions/1179309/how-to-enable-3des-ssl-ciphers-for-openssl-1-0-2k

Comment: ありがとうございます。なるほど、DESを有効化しないといけないんですね。教えていただいたURLをざっと見ましたが、OpenSSLを自分デコンパイルしないといけないのと、たぶんApacheも再コンパイルしないといけなさそうなので、時間がかかりそうです。また時間が取れそうなときに試してみます。

Comment: とりあえず、OpenSSLはなんとかビルドできた感じなので、Apacheをビルドしようとしているんですが、設定ファイルの場所はどうやって変更したらいいんでしょうか。現状「/etc/apache2」に設定ファイルとかその他もろもろがあるので、そこを参照するようにしたいんですが。あと、a2enconfとかa2ensiteとかa2enmodとかはどうやったら利用できるようになるんでしょうか。いろいろ調べてみてはいるんですが、あまりいい情報が見つからないので、参考サイトとかがあれば教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: Apache httpd を独自にコンパイル・インストールするのであれば、Ubuntu とは別のディレクトリにインストールした方がいいと思います。
a2enmod などの Ubuntu パッケージ固有のコマンドは利用できなくなりますが。

Comment: やはりそうですよね。いろいろ調べてみましたが、今の自分の力では難しそうなので、もう少し勉強してからにしようと思います。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

Ciphersuite を次のようにするとどうでしょうか。

```
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。変更してみましたが、状況は変わりませんでした。